# Custom Attribute on Product Listing Magento

Tags: magento-1.8, attributes, list.phtml

Greeting,

Though there are several answers to this question, just need to add AttributeCode to list.phtml page. But here lies my problem i am unable to edit my list.phtml. Is there any why through which i can locate correct list.phtml file my magento is using.

i am editing `app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/template/catalog/product/list.phtml` this file, but nothing is happening on fronthand.

I want to show the attribute both on homepage product lsitings & on category listings.
Please suggest what can i do.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `System > Configuration > Developer`, then pick the appropriate in the `Configuration Scope`. Once the page is refreshed, you will be able to turn `Template Path Hints` on (see image below). Then refresh your page on the frontend and it will give you the paths you are looking for.

[image: http://magentoexpertforum.com/i/2013/templatePathHints.jpg]

Also remember that for your attribute to be accessible on product listings pages, `Used in Product Listing` will need to be `On` for the attribute you are accessing.`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Extension for Template Hints

```
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/easy-template-path-hints.html
```